# Accessory coming on randomly and killing battery. GMC Canyon 2007

Tags: gmc, battery-drain, canyon

My 2007 GMC Canyon has had this problem for a couple months. All of the accessories turn on by itself after I have left the truck off and locked. I thought it was the ignition, because when I took the key out sometimes it stayed on and when I put the key back in and out again it would turn off. (It still does this even though the ignition barrel has been replaced). Or it seems to be off and I go back and check and it's on.

My dealership has run through the entire flow chart. Replaced the Body Control Module ... the ignition barrel ... the door switch and the fuse block. They are at the end of the flow chart and have checked wires and can't figure it out. I have had the truck since 2011 and never had a problem until recently. Help!

Comment: Also have taken the fuse out for the radio and the problem still happens just without the radio turning on

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! My suggestion is, the Body Control Module (BCM) is at fault. Doing a quick run through on the interwebz, the BCM on the Canyon/Colorado seems like it happens all the time. It could be you got a bad one from the dealership. The BCM controls a LOT of functions on these vehicles.

Comment: When you say it stays on, do you mean all the cluster lights stay on and the engine is not running? And this is different from normal RAP operation? And when you put the key back in again and remove it are you turning the key or are you just inserting and removing?

Comment: I am just inserting and removing. When I say it stays on or comes on itself... the engine is not running.  It's like when you just turn the key forward one click so you can turn the power on to roll up.the windows . The radio comes on.. all the dash lights . The power windows etc

Comment: Also they already replaced the bcm. And it did not fix it or change anything. That was the last item on the flow chart that they replaced. So it's not the bcm. It's going in again tomorrow or more testing.

Comment: Just to clarify on the dash lights are we talking illumination or things like the check engine, srs, abs etc... as well? The ignition barrel was replaced? How about the switch? What happens if you pull the RAP relay? Are there any aftermarket components installed?